# What is the most efficient way to set one bit of a register in ARM?

Tags: assembly, arm, bitwise-operators, pipeline

I'm writing ARM assembly code that at some point has to set a single bit of a register to 1. This is best done of course via "register-`or`-bitmask" method. However, according to ARM documentation, the Assembly `ORR` command (bitwise OR) does *not* take immediate values. In other words you can only bitwise-OR a value in one register with a value in another register. When you think about it, it makes sense because ARM instructions are themselves 32-bit long, so there's no way to cram a 32-bit mask into an instruction. However, writing an immediate value to a register just to use it right a way is inefficient because it produces a [read-after-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_%28computer_architecture%29#Read_After_Write_.28RAW.29) hazard which stalls the CPU. In general, what is the most efficient way to `ORR` a register with a mask without wasting a register on constantly keeping that mask in memory? Does ARM recommend anything?

Comment: What processor are you targetting?  Cortex-M3 has a [bit-banded](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.faqs/ka4203.html) memory region which is the best way to do this if you've got that option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
ORR r0, r1, #0x4
```

is perfectly fine in standard ARM. You can encode immediate values in a 32-bit ARM instruction, but their range is limited. [See this explanation](http://www.davespace.co.uk/arm/introduction-to-arm/immediates.html).

Your link points to the Thumb documentation; are you sure you need to be using Thumb instructions?

Comment: Sorry, ARM website redirects to some strange place. I'll remove the link.

Comment: I think we just found a fluke in the documentation. = ) Immediate mode is mentioned generally, but there's no separate page for it like for everything else in the manual like for everything else. Thanks = )

Comment: @Phonon My copies of the ARMARM (v7AR and v7M) both have ORR (Immediate) as a separate page. Which documentation are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Although ARM (or mips, and I assume others) cannot fit a full register sized immediate, ARM does have alu operations with immediate values.  And you are not limited to 0x00 to 0xFF you can

```
orr r0,r0,#0x02000000
```

for example, no problem.  0x00 to 0xFF shifted anywhere in the 32 bits some instructions might give you a ninth bit 0x000 to 0x1FF (shifted anywhere), at least I seem to remember something about that working (for one/some instructions).  You code the instruction as above and the assembler takes care of packing the immediate into the instruction for you.